# How to rewrite my code into from using tidyverse to data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have written a code:

```
df_all<- df1 %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels = df3$type)) %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  complete(type, fill = list(value = 0)) %>%
  left_join(df3)
```

How to rewrite it to using data.table? Im new in it, so i dont know? It would be just great if you help me with this.

Here is for what i use it:

I have a single column dataframe df3 with column type with all possible "types":

```
comment       type

used         enter 
used         open
used         close
used         update
not_used     delete
```

I get dataframe from my database. But in that dataframe, not all "types" might be. Here is example of that table:

```
ID    date            type           value
a1    2020-09-01       enter          18
a1    2020-09-01       close          15
a1    2020-09-02       enter          4
a2    2020-09-01       close          10
b1    2020-09-02       update         10
```

As you see ID a1 has only two types: enter and close. a2 has only close, b1 has only update.

I want to bind these two tables in that way, so "types" which were not in my table have value zero for each ID and date. So, how to bind these two tables to get this:

```
comment            ID    date            type           value
used               a1    2020-09-01       enter          18
used               a1    2020-09-01       open           0
used               a1    2020-09-01       close          15
used               a1    2020-09-01       update         0
not_used           a1    2020-09-01       delete         0
used               a1    2020-09-02       enter          4
used               a1    2020-09-02       open           0
used               a1    2020-09-02       close          0
used               a1    2020-09-02       update         0
not_used           a1    2020-09-02       delete         0
used               a2    2020-09-01       enter          0
used               a2    2020-09-01       open           0
used               a2    2020-09-01       close          10
used               a2    2020-09-01       update         0
not_used           a2    2020-09-01       delete         0
used               b1    2020-09-01       enter          0
used               b1    2020-09-01       open           0
used               b1    2020-09-01       close          0
used               b1    2020-09-01       update         10
not_used           b1    2020-09-01       delete         0
```

As you see, I also kept column "comment". How could i rewrite code as data.table?

Comment: In the code you have `count` column.  It is not in the example

Comment: What is `df3` in the code

Comment: @akrun i edited. its first dataframe

Comment: @akrun i removed first rbind part, now its just df1

Comment: In the example, is it the second example 'df1' and the first 'df3'?

Comment: @akrun yeah it is

Comment: Can you try the update

Comment: @akrun Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df1)[, `:=`(type, factor(type, levels = df3$type))][,  : 
  invalid type/length (closure/22400) in vector allocation

Comment: With the example you showed, it is working fine for me without any errors

Comment: @akrun and in [, type := factor(type, levels = df3$type)] which type is from which dataframe? In case if in df3 column "type" has other name?

Comment: Please check if the column name is correct.  Also, I would use `unique`

Comment: @akrun it works, but left_join(df3) part is missed. its necessary

Comment: Ok, then you can just do a join at the end .  updated

Comment: @akrun thanks a lot, and what in case if in df3 column type has name type1. its like [df3, on = .(type = type1)] ?

Comment: Yes, what ever is the column name, you can use it as `on = .(name1 = name2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the `type` of `factor`, use `CJ` (cross-join) to expand by ID, date, and type

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, type := factor(type, levels = unique(df3$type))][,
   CJ(ID, date, type = type, unique = TRUE)][df1,
    value := value, on = .(ID, date, type)][is.na(value),
     value := 0][df3, on = .(type)]
```

---

Or it can be done with `split`

```
setDT(df1)[, type := factor(type, levels = unique(df3$type))]
rbindlist(lapply(split(df1, df1[, .(ID, date)], drop = TRUE), 
   function(x) x[, CJ(ID, date, type = levels(x$type), unique = TRUE)][x, 
     value := value, on = .(ID, date, type)][is.na(value), value := 0][]))[df3, on = .(type)]))
```

-output

```
#    ID       date   type value  comment
# 1: a1 2020-09-01  enter    18     used
# 2: a1 2020-09-01   open     0     used
# 3: a1 2020-09-01  close    15     used
# 4: a1 2020-09-01 update     0     used
# 5: a1 2020-09-01 delete     0 not_used
# 6: a2 2020-09-01  enter     0     used
# 7: a2 2020-09-01   open     0     used
# 8: a2 2020-09-01  close    10     used
# 9: a2 2020-09-01 update     0     used
#10: a2 2020-09-01 delete     0 not_used
#11: a1 2020-09-02  enter     4     used
#12: a1 2020-09-02   open     0     used
#13: a1 2020-09-02  close     0     used
#14: a1 2020-09-02 update     0     used
#15: a1 2020-09-02 delete     0 not_used
#16: b1 2020-09-02  enter     0     used
#17: b1 2020-09-02   open     0     used
#18: b1 2020-09-02  close     0     used
#19: b1 2020-09-02 update    10     used
#20: b1 2020-09-02 delete     0 not_used
```

Comment: it says Error in `[.data.table`(rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[,  : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: @french_fries it must be from the `last step for `CJ`.  I didn't test it because there was no example.  Can you post an example to test. thanks

Comment: i added example and explanation

Comment: @french_fries are you sure the dplyr syntax worked for you with `rbind`

Comment: does your code gives desired result with example dataframe?

Comment: @french_fries i was trying your dplyr code on the data showed and it is giving errors especially the `rbind`

Comment: yeah i relived it, now its just one datfarame df1, which is second dataframe from example. and df3 is first dataframe from example with only two columns

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concise `data.table` version of OP's code:

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[df3, on = .(type)], by = .(ID, date)]
```

which returns the expected result (for the sake of clarity, the `NA`s in the `value` column are converted in a second step - see below)

> ```
>     ID       date   type value  comment
>  1: a1 2020-09-01  enter    18     used
>  2: a1 2020-09-01   open    NA     used
>  3: a1 2020-09-01  close    15     used
>  4: a1 2020-09-01 update    NA     used
>  5: a1 2020-09-01 delete    NA not_used
>  6: a1 2020-09-02  enter     4     used
>  7: a1 2020-09-02   open    NA     used
>  8: a1 2020-09-02  close    NA     used
>  9: a1 2020-09-02 update    NA     used
> 10: a1 2020-09-02 delete    NA not_used
> 11: a2 2020-09-01  enter    NA     used
> 12: a2 2020-09-01   open    NA     used
> 13: a2 2020-09-01  close    10     used
> 14: a2 2020-09-01 update    NA     used
> 15: a2 2020-09-01 delete    NA not_used
> 16: b1 2020-09-02  enter    NA     used
> 17: b1 2020-09-02   open    NA     used
> 18: b1 2020-09-02  close    NA     used
> 19: b1 2020-09-02 update    10     used
> 20: b1 2020-09-02 delete    NA not_used
> ```

For each group of unique `ID`, `date` combinations the subset of rows of `df1` is right joined with `df3` on `type` which completes the missing rows for each subset. Because a right join is used instead of tidyr::complete() there is no need here to coerce `type` to factor with the all factor levels. Also, `data.table` has preserved the order of `df3` rows during the join.

For converting the `NA`s in the `value` column, there are 4 different approaches available, which all return the same result:

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[df3, on = .(type)], by = .(ID, date)][is.na(value), value := 0L][]
setDT(df1)[, .SD[df3, on = .(type)], by = .(ID, date)][, value := fcoalesce(value, 0L)][]
setDT(df1)[, .SD[df3, on = .(type)], by = .(ID, date)][, value := nafill(value, fill = 0L)][]
setnafill(setDT(df1)[, .SD[df3, on = .(type)], by = .(ID, date)], fill = 0L, cols = "value")[]
```

> ```
>      ID       date   type value  comment
>  1: a1 2020-09-01  enter    18     used
>  2: a1 2020-09-01   open     0     used
>  3: a1 2020-09-01  close    15     used
>  4: a1 2020-09-01 update     0     used
>  5: a1 2020-09-01 delete     0 not_used
>  6: a1 2020-09-02  enter     4     used
>  7: a1 2020-09-02   open     0     used
>  8: a1 2020-09-02  close     0     used
>  9: a1 2020-09-02 update     0     used
> 10: a1 2020-09-02 delete     0 not_used
> 11: a2 2020-09-01  enter     0     used
> 12: a2 2020-09-01   open     0     used
> 13: a2 2020-09-01  close    10     used
> 14: a2 2020-09-01 update     0     used
> 15: a2 2020-09-01 delete     0 not_used
> 16: b1 2020-09-02  enter     0     used
> 17: b1 2020-09-02   open     0     used
> 18: b1 2020-09-02  close     0     used
> 19: b1 2020-09-02 update    10     used
> 20: b1 2020-09-02 delete     0 not_used
> ```